# Getting rid of duplicates

Tags: python-2.7

Can someone help? 
I have a file like this:

```
file = """he is a good man
she is a beautiful woman
this is a clever student
he is a bad neighbour"""
```

And I want to mark the adjectives in the file, so I extracted them in a list and I want to replace them in the original file in another format, like between brackets. So the list adjectives looks like this

```
ad =  "good, bad, clever, beautiful,"
```

I tried this

```
for line in file.splitlines():
    for a in ad.split(','):
        if a in line:
            newline = line.replace(s, '[' + s + ']')
            result = file.replace(line, newline)
            print result
```

this gives me this result with duplicates:

```
he is a [good] man
she is a beatiful woman
this is a clever student
he is a bad neighbor

he is a good man
she is a[ beatiful] woman
this is a clever student
he is a bad neighbor

he is a good man
she is a beatiful woman
this is a[ clever] student
he is a bad neighbor

he is a good man
she is a beatiful woman
this is a clever student
he is a[ bad] neighbor
```

while I expect result like this

```
he is a [good] man
she is a [beautiful] woman
this is a [clever] student
he is a [bad] neighbour
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your loop. You aren't splitting your adjectives well and the splitline is unnecessary if you are going to use replace. So, your code should be as follows:

```
adj = [word.strip() for word in ad.split(",") if word != ""]
for a in adj:
  if a in file:
    file = file.replace(a, '[' + a + ']')
print file
```